# Write xml from textbox to existing xml file without replacing old text, just adding new

Tags: c#, xml, textbox

So... I have 2 textboxes and 1 button.
And when I input data to those textboxes, and click the button, I would like it to enter xml file and add new element with attributes to it, without replacing it.
After a lot of browsing I managed to do something that replaced all text in my xml file, or I got an error, so I decided to post a question here.

So this is how my xml file looks:

```
<library>
<book name="Her way" price="20"></book>
<book name="His way" price="20"></book>
</library>
```

and what I'm trying to do is to insert:

```
<book name="Their way" price="22"></book>
```

bellow last one so it would look like:

```
<library>
<book name="Her way" price="20"></book>
<book name="His way" price="20"></book>
<book name="Their way" price="22"></book>
</library>
```

And every time I click button again, it adds it same way, ofc I would change name and price in textbox.

I came up with this code, but I am fairly new to xml so I don't know how to modify it or make it work.

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("booklibrary.xml");
            doc.Add(new XElement("book",
            new XAttribute("name", textBox1.Text),
            new XAttribute("price", textBox3.Text)));
            doc.Save("booklibrary.xml");
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does your current code doing?  Does it throw an error?  If so, post it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `XDocument` if you aren't working with namespaces. Just use an `XElement` and your code will work:

```
var library = XElement.Load("booklibrary.xml");
library.Add(new XElement("book",
new XAttribute("name", textBox1.Text),
new XAttribute("price", textBox3.Text)));
library.Save("booklibrary.xml");
```

Because you used `XDocument`, `Add` tried to add the new element *next* to the root element `<library>` instead of inside it, causing an exception because there can be only one root element. Several illustrative examples [can be found on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675196.aspx).

By using `XElement` as shown above, this problem is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I would use LINQ to XML instead, very easy to use and tons of functionality!:

```
XElement ele = XElement.Load("booklibrary.xml");
            ele.Element("library").Add(
                new XElement("book",
                             new XAttribute("name", textBox1.Text),
                             new XAttribute("price", textBox3.Text)));
ele.Save();
```

This is much cleaner, and it uses the new .NET stuff.

Comment: he's using LINQ to XML already. Although using `XElement` *is* better than using `XDocument`.